# Is there a command that does what button clicks do for Windows 10 settings?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Windows frequently messes with my settings especially after an update, for example it changes my active hours to 8:00am-5:00pm. I can manually navigate to various settings via button clicks, but *surely* there must be a command line that does what searching through on-screen control panels and finding the right setting does. *Is* there a command line method of setting the active hours? Eventually I want to generalize this to other settings, such as "setting the default program for opening files with the extention .html", but I'm starting with something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to restore theses settings is with a Registry script. For example, to [enable *Active Hours* and to set the start and times](https://windowsloop.com/enable-active-hours/):

- Set up *Active Hours* using the Windows Update Control Panel.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `regedit`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to open *Regedit*.
- Go to the key `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`. If the values for *SetActiveHours*, ActiveHoursStart* and *ActiveHoursEnd* are present, export the entire `WindowsUpdate` key to a .reg file with a suitable name, such as `updatekey.reg`.
- If the values are *not* in the above key, go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\Update` and export the `Update` key.

[image: Registry Update key]

Now, whenever you want to restore that setting, just double-click the .reg file.

You may need to search for a particular setting, such as *ActiveHoursStart*, since the setting might be in one or more location [per questioner, user6726, comment]. If you have multiple settings to correct, you could manually edit the separable scripts to combine them into one, but keeping them separate allows you to run only those needed.

Comment: I'll mention that it was under in a different place, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update\ActiveHoursStart, so the "key" is knowing to search for ActiveHoursStart.